# How to automatically change Date using jQuery to exactly 1 Month

Tags: jquery, html, datetimepicker

I am using **jQuery** to get Dates on my WebPage which works fine. My requirement is that if a User selects the **ValidFrom** date as **01/01/2019** (1st january, 2018) or for that matter any random date, the **ValidTo** date should automatically increase by **1 Month**.

The **ValidTo** date should change in accordance with the **ValidFrom** date.

Following is my code for the same:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ValidFrom').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            step: 30,
            minDate: new Date()
        });
        $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',

            step: 30,
            minDate: new Date()
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Comment: have you tried anything?  should be just a case of detecting when #ValidFrom changes and then setting #ValidTo value to required date once you've calculated what that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the code should be like.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ValidFrom').datetimepicker({
        datepicker: true,
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        step: 30,
        minDate: new Date(),
        onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
            var date = new Date($input.val());
            date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
            date = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
            $('#ValidTo').val(date);
        },

    });
    $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker({
        datepicker: true,
        timepicker: false,
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        step: 30,
        minDate: new Date()
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI This example uses `datepicker` plugin (act accordingly).
You can use the `onSelect` jQuery-UI datepicker event.

```js
var config = config || {};


config.datepicker_defaults = {
  format: 'm/d/Y',
  minDate: new Date(),
};


jQuery(function($) {

  var $from = $('#ValidFrom'),
    $to = $('#ValidTo');

  $from.datepicker($.extend(config.datepicker_defaults, {
    onSelect: function() {
      var dateTo = new Date($(this).datepicker('getDate'));
      dateTo.setMonth(dateTo.getMonth() + 1);

      $to.datepicker('option', 'minDate', $(this).datepicker('getDate'));
      $to.datepicker('setDate', dateTo);
    }
  }));

  $to.datepicker(config.datepicker_defaults);

});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<input type="text" id="ValidFrom" readonly>
<input type="text" id="ValidTo" readonly>
```